# PHP/PDO Select Statement with Multiple Bound Where Conditions Returning 500 Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the first time that I am trying to query mysql according to multiple where conditions in my PDO select statement and with several different approaches I am consistently getting a 500 internal error.

Here is my query code:

```
$book = 'Revelation';
$chapter = 3;
$start = 5; 
$end = 8;
$sv = $start;
$ref = '';

$references = '<b>'.$book.' '.$chapter.':'.$start.'-'.$end.'</b><br>';


while($sv <= $end){

    $selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT verse, this_verse_id FROM verses_of_bible 

        WHERE book_name = :BOOK
        AND chapter_id = :CHAPTER
        AND this_verse_id = :VID

    LIMIT 1");

    $selectqup->bindValue(':BOOK',$book,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $selectqup->bindValue(':CHAPTER',$chapter,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $selectqup->bindValue(':VID',$sv,PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $selectqup->execute(); 


    while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $this_verse_id = $row['this_verse_id'];
        $verse = $row['verse']; 

        $ref .= '<p><b>'.$this_verse_id.'</b> '.$verse.'</p>';
    }

    $sv++;
}

echo '<div class="grid">';
echo $references.$ref;
echo '</div>';
```

Not quite sure how to handle this... assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check your php/server error logs which should tell you the cause of the 500. On linux usually located in `/var/log/...`

Comment: You don't need `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: I can't find anything in the logs @Purgatory and  Removing LIMIT 1 Did not resolve the issue. Thank you for your input